# Where can I find hashes for Mozilla applications?

Tags: thunderbird, firefox, hashing, md5

What is a reliable source for [cryptographic hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) values for Mozilla applications?

---

**Update 1**: the value from http://releases.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/thunderbird/releases/latest/MD5SUMS, A344903A030EC2CA9630407C9736FE11, matched the output from [md5sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Md5sum) (in [Cygwin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin) 1.7.1) on the downloaded file.

---

In particular what is the [MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) hash for the Windows version of [Thunderbird](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla_Thunderbird) 3.0.1? There is one listed at 
[this site](http://finalbuilds.edskes.net/thunderbird.htm), but I think only the ones coming from a Mozilla controlled domain can be trusted.

Background: I have downloaded Thunderbird 3.0.1, but I could not control from which server. I would like to be sure that the file has not been tampered with.

Comment: Mozilla's Windows installers are also signed themselves - you can see the signature information in file properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the [mozilla ftp](http://releases.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/thunderbird/releases/latest/), you can find [MD5](http://releases.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/thunderbird/releases/latest/MD5SUMS) and [SHA1](http://releases.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/thunderbird/releases/latest/SHA1SUMS) checksum.

If you need, you can also find hashes for other versions of thunderbird or any other mozilla softwares.

Comment: There seems to only be a PGP signature for the Windows version of Thunderbird 3.0.1, http://releases.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/thunderbird/releases/latest/win32/en-US/ Isn't a public key needed to check the file? If yes, which public key would it be? (E.g. for the application or for Mozilla?)

Comment: Only look at this file (MD5 file I linked above): http://releases.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/thunderbird/releases/latest/MD5SUMS -> there you can see " a344903a030ec2ca9630407c9736fe11  ./win32/en-US/Thunderbird Setup 3.0.1.exe "

Comment: It is important to use GPG to verify the integrity of the SHA1SUMS file.  It could be easily tampered with in transit because the site doesn't use HTTPS.

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen: where would the public key come from? Isn't http://releases.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/thunderbird/releases/latest/KEY also unsecure?

Comment: Ideally, you would ask someone you would get someone you trust to sign the key (http://www.rubin.ch/pgp/weboftrust.en.html).  But I agree at a certain point the extra verification is not worth the effort.

Comment: The Mozilla FTP site you mentioned doesn't seem to contain any files other than a README now. Do you happen to know of an updated site?

Answer (score 0):

Summary: look under URL https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/ to find "releases" subdirectory of the application directory, find the exact version in the releases directory, and the signed files with SHA256 and SHA512 hashes are there.

---

The accepted answer is 11 years old, and Mozilla has revamped its download infrastructure at least once since then, and its release repository directory structure at least twice. Currently, to find signed SHA256 and SHA512 sums you really need to know where to look, Mozilla does not make them easy to find.

Now the Mozilla download pages do not have download URLs which include the application version, and you need to know that version to find the hashes. If you are anyway going to download the application, it suffices to look at the (default) filename for the downloaded file. Otherwise running a script similar to the following Python3 script will find that filename without actually having to download the whole file:

```
import urllib.request

# cert_file = "MITM.crt"

latest_url = "https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-latest&os=win64&lang=en-US"

request = urllib.request.Request(latest_url)
request.get_method = (lambda : 'HEAD')

orbo_inspect_active = False

response = urllib.request.urlopen(request) # if need custom cert add : cafile = cert_file

latest_filename = response.geturl()
latest_filename = latest_filename[latest_filename.rfind("/") + 1 : ]

print("FILENAME =", latest_filename)

# and then look at contents of appropriate subdirectory of
#    https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/
```

and then the SHA256 file would be found at URL

```
"https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/{application_name:s}/releases/{version_string:s}/SHA256SUMS".format(...)
```

I won't post my personal solution for checking the signature because everyone will have their own preference how to do that (e.g., invoke "gpg" using the "subprocess" module, or use a crypto PyPI package, etc...).